# Validate presence if condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I know validation in Rails is fairly simple, but I can't figure out how to validate if one condition is met. I have two signup forms, one with and without the following code:

```
<%= f.select :buyer_type, ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'], {include_blank: "Please Select"}, { class: "form-control" , required: 'required'} %>
```

And both have the following code, changed depending on the role:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :registered_as, value: 'buyer' %>

<%= f.hidden_field :registered_as, value: 'developer' %>
```

In my `user.rb` file, I have the following line to help validate the `f.select` option:

```
validates :buyer_type, presence: true
```

But when I test signing up on the other form, which doesn't have the f.select option, it won't submit the form.

Is there a way I can edit the `validates :buyer_type` in order to only activate for the form with the `f.select` option, using the `f.hidden_field :registered_as` component of the code?

EDIT: I've tried things along the lines of this:

```
validates :buyer_type, presence: true
    if :registered_as value: 'buyer'
    end
```

But no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#validates` is a class method on `ActiveRecord` objects, and it takes an optional argument `:if`.

The value of the `:if` parameter can be one of a few things.

If it is a symbol it will call the instance method with that name on the object being validated. For example `validates :buyer_type, presence: true, if: :buyer?`

Conceptually it would do an `object.send(:buyer?)` on the object being validated. If that method returns a truthy value (anything other than `nil` or `false`) then the validation will run.

It would be implemented like so:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :buyer_type, presence: true, if: :buyer?

  def buyer?
    registered_as == "buyer"
  end
end
```

However for simple validations, rather than adding a method to your object you can use a Lambda - an anonymous function. This is more concise and easier to read for simple conditionals that don't need to be reused. This is the `stabby lambda` syntax (because `->` looks like a stabby thing).

Here is a simple example of using a lambda function. It assigns the lambda function to the variable `x` and then calls the function.

```
irb(main):001:0> x = -> { puts "hi" }
=> #<Proc:0x00007ff930921068@(irb):1 (lambda)>
irb(main):002:0> x.call
hi
=> nil
```

Here is how it is used in a validation:

```
validates :buyer_type, presence: true, if: -> { registered_as == 'buyer' }
```

The body of the lambda runs in the context of the object being validated, so again you have access to the object's instance methods for validation.

The rails guide on validation is a great resource on this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

You can read more about Procs and Lambdas here https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Proc.html

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: @AmitVerma this is true - and this solution did work for me. I'm new to Ruby so I don't know the syntax very well. I don't understand why ```->``` is used instead of ```=>``` or how ```==``` works. I've got some more experienced devs that I work with so I'm hoping I pick all of this up as I go along.

Comment: I took some time to expand my answer. Hope it is helpful!